# Bind ignores ifdef it is enclosed in

Tags: system-verilog

Very simple example:

```
`ifdef the_define
  bind(....);
`endif
```

The `bind()` is attempted whether `the_define` is defined or not.
Why? If it is correct behavior, how can binds be made conditional?

Comment: Please show the **actual** code. The directives syntax is wrong as is.

Comment: Please share your testcase (make it simple), and tell up what simulator and version you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work as expected:

```
`timescale 1ns/1ns
module tb;
  initial #10 $finish;
endmodule
module binder();
  initial $display("%m @ %2t",$time);
  final   $display("%m @ %2t", $time);
endmodule
`ifdef the_define
bind tb binder ibind();
`endif
```

Compile with `+define+the_define` results:

```
tb.ibind @  0
tb.ibind @ 10
```

Compile without `+define+the_define` results:

```
binder @  0
binder @ 10
```

The without example make sense because `binder` is now considered a top module. Some simulators have a option to specify a single top, treating the others top modules as unused. Another way of preventing `binder` from being a top module is to move it into a library file/director (typically included via `-v`/`-y`). Historically, I have seen some simulators give errors with this method because it optimizes out unused modules before considering `bind`; so experiment with your own tool-set. Another way is to  `` `ifdef `` the module itself; easy to do but not very flexible if you have many configurations.

`bind` must be known at compile/elaboration time. It is not a simulation run-time options.

Other possibilities are:

- you are not doing a clean recompile (aka artifact from previous compile)
- something else in your environment is setting defining `the_define` (probably temporarily)